# his Grace's personal arrangements

Tags: word-usage

> Two days before the case was down for hearing the advance reporter of
>   an important syndicate obtained an interview with the Duke for the
>   purpose of gleaning some final grains of information concerning **his
>   Grace's personal arrangements** during the trial.
>
> from [The Unkindest Blow](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/UnkiBlow802.shtml), a short story by Saki

Why does Saki use "his Grace's " instead of "the Grace's "?

What does "personal arrangements" mean? His clothes?

Answer (score 2):

"His Grace" is the Duke. As a sign of courtesy and deference, British nobility and royalty have "forms of address". Dukes are formally addressed as "Your Grace", (e.g. good morning, Your Grace), and when someone is speaking about a duke, they may use "His Grace", (e.g. His Grace is ready for his lunch). These were much more often used 100 years ago when Saki was writing. There may be an element of sarcasm in Saki's use of the form.

The Duke's "personal arrangements" are not specified, but could include relatively mundane things such as where he is staying, who is accompanying him, etc.

[Forms of address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forms_of_address_in_the_United_Kingdom#Peers,_peeresses_and_non-peerage)

Answer (score 1):

Michael Harvey has answered your first question: *His Grace* is a way of referring to the Duke. Compare *her Majesty*, a way of referring to the Queen.

On your second question, no his "personal arrangements" does not mean his clothes. Its meaning is not precisely defined, but given that this is a divorce case, it is clear that it means something like "how he lives his private life", and especially who he lives it with.

Comment: Why is it clear that it means something like "how he lives his private life", and especially who he lives it with?

Answer (score 0):

The term "his Grace" goes way back to early English. At one time, it was considered rude to address nobility directly. If you were talking to Queen Elizabeth, you couldn't just call her "Elizabeth", and even calling her "Queen" was seen as much too familiar except by other high nobility.

Instead, commoners would address a *quality the noble possessed* as if that were the person. Over time we built up a whole set of standard terms of address for very important people, and it was important to use the correct one.  And eventually, you'd use that phrase even when talking *about* the person.

Instead of saying, "Yes, Queen," you'd say, "Yes, your Majesty."  Instead of saying, "The Pope said...", you'd say, "His Holiness said..." (or if there were a lot of people around who could be a 'his holiness', you could say, "His Holiness the Pope said...")

We aren't very strict about that sort of thing today, and it only really still is used with reference to particularly important royalty or the high ranks of the Catholic Church (and even then only if you're trying to be polite), or in a historical context.

"Personal arrangements" means "the way he arranges his personal life". In other words "information concerning the Duke's private life", the things normally kept hidden from the public.  Not necessarily because it's bad and he wants it hidden, but just because it's nobody's business. It could include just about anything, like health conditions, whether he's on a diet, what companies he has invested in, where he's living, who he's sleeping with, and so on.

In the context, probably the reporter wants to know where the Duke is going to be staying during the trial, which he might be reluctant to share.